# Mapbox not updating from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

Last month, we edited the names of schools that were incorrect in OSM. In particular, the name of the school in the upper portion was renamed and the school that was once listed toward the bottom has closed. Below is the correct map:

[image]

Though, it does not seem that Mapbox tiles (which we use with Leaflet) has used the updated mapping data. That is, both locations are still listed as schools. Below is the current Mapbox map which has the incorrect data:

[image]

Yet, from the documentation I've gathered, it appears that Mapbox data uses the OSM replication feed so I would expect that the data is updated pretty quickly. Our call to Mapbox is `https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` which renders the incorrect maps.

Are schools (and other special buildings) not updated with the same frequency as other geographies (i.e., streets)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mapbox no longer applies OpenStreetMap edits right away and won't guarantee any timeframe for edits to appear. I've heard that their system for applying changes is backlogged and has lost some changes.

You could try contacting them at help@mapbox.com, but I doubt they'd do anything to fix their problems.

Sources:
Conversations with people at Mapbox and https://twitter.com/Anonymaps/status/913812009547902978